# 1x decking wood

Tags: repair

I have 3 porches. One is half decking wood, and the other two are just what I had laying around.

I am looking for some 1x's to go over what I have. I am disabled and on a very low income so I am looking for some cheap decking wood to do it myself. I am in jonesboro Tn. and need something fairly close.

Does anyone have any or know the best place to get it? I can't really afford lowes or home depot.

Comment: May i suggest a quick visit to the help section, where you will find that this sort of request (not even a question, really) is far off-topic. http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

A lot of places will let you take their discarded shipping pallets for free.  Those ought to work for free lumber.

They will be unfinished, so you'll need some paint.  Lowes and Home Depot always have clearance paint, stuff that customers return because the color doesn't come out quite right when they mix it.  Watch for the exterior one-step paint and primer and if you're not fussy about the color you might not have to watch too long.